# Disable deserialzation Database Project Schema

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, database-project

Recently we started working with Database project in Visual Studio 2010. I have added a reasonably large database to the solution and imported all objects. All warnings have been eliminated so it builds fine.

The one thing that really annoys me is that when you open the solution, the database project will start to load the database schema which takes some time (minutes) and uses a lot of resources. Practically I am not able to start working the moment the solution was loaded.

Is there any way to disable or change that behavior other than removing the database project from the solution or other hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: unload the project.
This way it will (locally) not load the next time you open the solution.
If you need to work on the database project, just load it, work on it and unload it again.